# Deploy Airflow 2.0+ on Azure

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have started learning/trying Airflow. Part of my research, I have installed airflow in my local through Docker. I referred official page [Airflow Install Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

I am looking for a (standard) process when I can deploy Airflow to Azure.

Can I directly use same docker-compose file for that ?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Likely the easiest way is to use AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) and use the official Helm Chart of Apache Airflow from the Apache Airflow community to deploy Airflow on it:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I reckon, Installing Airflow through Docker-compose.yml on Azure wouldn't be the right approach. It is probably encouraged for local installations only.

The way we have set this up in Azure is like this:
**Database**: *Azure Database for PostgreSQL server*
**Webserver + Scheduler**: *Azure App Service on a Linux App Service Plan*
**Docker**: *Azure Container Registry*

1. Build the Docker image (either locally or in CICD pipeline)
2. Push the Docker image to Azure Container Registry
3. Setup Postgres server and create airflow database
4. Setup Azure App Service to pull Docker image from ACR (You can also setup continuous integration). Remember to configure Environment variables.

Obviously, as Jarek mentioned, you could also go with setting up AKS.

Comment: Thank you for your steps. I am looking for some reference where this process is explained. Can you suggest some for me?

Comment: And one more question, which is the cost-effective (Azure service plan perspective)

Comment: @techrhl Unfortunately, I couldn't find a reference myself. I had to do a lot of trial and error based on container deployment for other services on App Service. On that note, I am planning to put together a blog that has full details. I will post it here when its ready.

Comment: @techrhl we are using Premium1 V2 as our Azure App Service Plan.

Comment: Do you suggest a Dockerfile for the above scenario that you mentioned ?

Comment: @techrhl I use a Dockerfile and build the Docker image through Azure DevOps pipelines. However, to be honest, I haven't tried any other way.

Comment: I followed the steps

1. Cloned Airflow git to local
2. Made changes (main branch)
3. Pushed to Azure repos
4. Created pipeline to build and push docker image to acr (Azure Container Registry)
3. I have created a Postgre service instance on Azure
4. ????

I am confused about starting an app service using container image.
Where should I mention/write commands "airflow webserver" and "airflow scheduler" ??

Comment: @techrhl Does your Airflow repo have an entrypoint.sh file in it? You can either use something that Puckel/docker-airflow offers (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) OR pass the commands through Dockerfile using CMD commands. FYI - I have an entrypoint.sh file where I instantiate them.

Comment: Vinay, Can this (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) work with airflow 2.0 ?

Comment: I am looking for a simple template like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/deploying-apache-airflow-in-azure-to-build-and-run-data-pipelines/

Comment: @techrhl the puckel's docker airflow image doesn't directly work with Airflow 2.0, but what I did was use it as a reference to build my own. You would need to change the version in the Dockerfile as well as copy the new `airflow.cfg` file from version Airflow 2.0

Comment: @VinayKulkarni Did you write the blog with full details? I'd be interested in reading it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the preconfigured images of Kubernertes AirFlow2 packaged by Bitnami. And perform the Deploy in AKS

[bitnami.airflow](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/bitnami.airflow-multitier?tab=Overview)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30053513)

Comment: There's only one review for that package and it's 1-star